# Fiddler Indy HTTP processes only 1 request

Tags: delphi, fiddler, indy

I am using Indy 10.6.0.5122 in Delphi XE6

When I try to debug a TIdHTTP instance with Fiddler, Fiddler only processes 1 request. The next request gets stuck. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

My code:

```
  IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := 'localhost';
  IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8888;
  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
  IdHTTP1.Get('https://www.google.com');
```

Fiddler and Indy gets the response of the very first request (if it's not a 302).

But after another request (e.g. a redirect), TidHTTP shows connection gracefully closed.

Comment: I presume the proxy is needed for fiddler? You should use wireshark...

Comment: Fiddler *is* the proxy. And Wireshark cannot (easily) capture traffic between two endpoints on localhost

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think it is a Fiddler issue, but I can't find any settings or anything that would make sense in order to work. A request really works just once.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce. The current version of Indy is 10.6.2.5393, please update your copy and see if the problem still occurs for you. I am using the latest Indy with the latest Fiddler (4.6.3.50306), and am able to make multiple HTTPS requests using the same `TIdHTTP` object when connected to Fiddler.

Comment: what i mean is that you need to use wireshark as the real code wont use the proxy and hence you are testing a different code path?